# Git - ran 'git init' multiple times, realized I lost data after several attempts

Tags: git, recovery

Yesterday I was messing around with starting version control in a project I was working on. I am essentially totally new to using git, and was trying to run the "first steps" that I thought I remembered from some blog post about "Getting Started with Git" but messed up the order several times and got mixed up, so I would delete the .git and start over.

All of these .git folders went to my recycle bin, and I finally got through the first steps by reading the manual, got through the `init` process and thought I was finished with that.

Hop on this morning and once I dive into the directories of my project I discover my entire project is delete from inside of them. So I try to go to the trash can, restore the .git folders , move them to unique directories and clone them, pull them, just trying to run every troubleshooting process I can find online for each repo. I have had no success thus far.

Like I said Im fairly new to git and honestly don't know where to go. I feel like running all of these random commands is just making things worse and confusing me, right now I have 4 versions of `<project_dir>_redo` folders, each with their own nearly identical version of a .git folder with varying numbers of "commits", different content in the `/objects` and `/refs` folders etc. and I don't even know where to begin to see if I am making progress, messing things up more or what.

Am i totally screwed or is there still hope?

I can edit the post to include more info, I just don't know if posting 11 pictures of the directories is particularly helpful.

EDIT
I have tried to run `git log` in the folder with each of the .git files and every one results in
`fatal: your current branch 'main' does not have any commits yet`

The best lead I have on the correct git directory is this one that has this structure:

```
.git
├── branches
├── COMMIT_EDITMSG
├── config
├── description
├── hooks
│   ├── applypatch-msg.sample
│   ├── commit-msg.sample
│   ├── fsmonitor-watchman.sample
│   ├── post-update.sample
│   ├── pre-applypatch.sample
│   ├── pre-commit.sample
│   ├── pre-merge-commit.sample
│   ├── prepare-commit-msg.sample
│   ├── pre-push.sample
│   ├── pre-rebase.sample
│   ├── pre-receive.sample
│   ├── push-to-checkout.sample
│   └── update.sample
├── index
├── info
│   └── exclude
├── logs
│   └── refs
│       ├── heads
│       │   ├── index_form
│       │   └── master
│       └── remotes
│           └── facili
│               └── master
├── objects
│   ├── 05
│   │   └── 632ca44c03b4aa90a5768075c40231af2bc329
│  ### About  100 files with hashes etc. ###
│   ├── info
│   └── pack
└── refs
    ├── heads
    │   ├── index_form # the first "branch" I made
    │   └── master
    ├── remotes
    │   └── facili
    │       └── master
    └── tags
```

Comment: Not enough information. Git is about commits. Did you do any add-and-commit? Then everything you committed is in a git folder and you can checkout a branch to retrieve it. If not, not.

Comment: You don't have to clone the recycle-bin `.git`, just change working directory *into* it and run `git log` to see what if any commits it contains. Use `git log -p` to view each commit as a patch, if that helps.

Comment: Also may I suggest you stop thrashing around and enacting robotic commands and learn what Git is before using it? Here's my intro: https://www.biteinteractive.com/picturing-git-conceptions-and-misconceptions/

Comment: @matt Yeah, like I said, I got to the point where I was feeling like I was done yesterday by reading the full 20-page "Getting Started/ What is git?" section of the Git documentation. Just that suddenly discovering you may have lost a months worth of work kind of tends to make one act a little desperately.

Comment: This is why you make backups, and why people have been saying for decades that you should make backups, and yet nobody ever seems to think *they* need to make backups. (No, this is not helpful to the situation at hand, but frankly, the situation at hand would rarely *be* at hand if people made backups.)

Comment: You only lost work if you didn't commit. If you didn't commit, that's like editing a file and you never hit Save. If you did commit, you're fine. You still have not answered the question: what did you actually _do?_

Answer (score 1):

Take the *.git* folder that you like, and put it into a completely empty folder. In the Terminal, `cd` into that folder. Then, don't say `git init` or any other thrashy stuff; just say `git checkout master`. (If you were already on `master`, you might have to say `git checkout --force master` instead.) Presto, all your files will appear.

If you think you might get better results with a different *.git* folder, do the same experiment that that one. And so forth.

Comment: I have done that with every folder thus far and I always get a msg like `fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`

Comment: That would happen if you didn't `cd` into the correct folder.

Comment: @matt I did what you have suggested in this answer. I took a `.git` folder of a pre-existing repository and copied it into a completely new folder outside of any source control. Then, I `cd`ed into this new folder and ran `git checkout master`. I expected that the files and folders would be created under this new folder as siblings of the `.git` folder that I copied. However, that does not happen. The terminal says: `Already on 'master' Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.` Could you please clarify where one should expect to see the files/folders appear?

Comment: @Tryer But what if you say `git checkout --force master`?

Comment: @matt Yes, that indeed does the trick. `git checkout master` only lists the files/folders in the terminal and ends up finally saying `Already on 'master' Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.`. `git checkout --force master` recreates all files and folders in the new folder as siblings of `.git` folder. The terminal then says `Already on 'master' Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.`

Comment: @Tryer Yeah, you can see why this happens. The `.git` folder carries with it a knowledge of what is HEAD right now. So if you ask to checkout what is already HEAD, Git just short-circuits the whole process and assumes it has nothing to do. `force` overcomes the short-circuit. This arises only because you happened to checkout the branch you were already on. I'll add this consideration to my answer. Thanks!